# Display only top child of stackpane

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX and am making a toolbar for sorting and filtering. I would like only one of sort or filter so show at any one time. I've heard that I can add these options to a stack pane and then apply the .toFront() method on the options that I'd like to show at any time. However, all options still appear. I'd like for only one to appear at a time.

Here is my code:

```
StackPane sortAndOrFilterStackPane = new StackPane();
    HBox sortOptionsHBox = makeSortOptions();
    HBox filterOptionsHBox = makeFilterOptions();
    sortAndOrFilterStackPane.getChildren().addAll(sortOptionsHBox, filterOptionsHBox);
    sortOptionsHBox.toFront();
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFxsO.jpg) is a screenshort of how it looks.

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: The answer in the linked duplicate will only work if the different nodes are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
sortOptionsHBox.toFront();
```

do

```
filterOptionsHBox.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Thank you! So then if I can just set visible why would someone want to change the order of a stackpane, out of curiosity?

Comment: There are use cases where you may want to be able to see multiple nodes but change the z-order, e.g. images with layers, vector drawing programs, etc.